# $p$-group isomorphic to some $p$-Sylow

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-isomorphism, sylow-theory

If  $G$ is a $p$-group such it's order is $p^n$, is it possible that some Sylow $p$-group $S$  from say $H$, is isomorphic to $G$? Under what conditions that will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take another prime $q \neq p$ and take $\mathbb{Z}_q$ make a new group H by direct product of G and $\mathbb{Z}_q$. G is a sylow p subgroup of H here. It will always happen.

Comment: Thanks for this example, but $G$ is isomorphic to????

Comment: $G \times \bar{0}$